# Custom fonts with Printmaker

Tags: plugin-printmaker

I'm generating a PDF from a template using the Printmaker plugin.
My CSS is being picked up and rendered mostly correctly and
if the template is rendered to screen as HTML then the fonts work. However I can't get the fonts to work with the PDF generation.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get the font information embedded within the PDF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Make sure your fonts are TTF.
- If you're loading them by remote URL, make sure the `isRemoteEnabled` is set to `true`.
- If you're changing weights, make sure to use the named weights in your CSS (`normal`, `bold`) rather than numeric weights.

*(These are limitations of the underlying DOMPDF library, which is used in Printmaker 1.x. The next release of Printmaker, for Craft 3, uses a much nicer rendering engine, which will eliminate these limitations.)*

Comment: My particular issue was down to the paths but the weights and isRemoteEnabled are top tips so I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seemed to be a matter of requiring the full URL to the font file and removal of any weight declarations in the CSS.